# In Natural language processing, how to find data set for scientific papers

Tags: nlp

i'm new in data science and trying to make application that classify the scientific papers to (AI,Machine Learning, NLP,...) 
i spend a lot of time trying to find data set for scientific papers but not found.
any help to find the data set?

Answer (score 0):

I believe https://arxiv.org/ is the best source for scientific papers.
 There are no particular datasets, but you can write a simple crawler and download articles for particular topics.